# Como ler uma DLL com Cordova ou Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, apache-cordova, wcf, dll

Estou criando um *app* que para fazer a comunicação com meu servidor eu preciso criar um *hash* variável que depende da classe, função e parâmetros que estou enviando. o servidor valida essas informações e só então continua seu processo.

Hoje, a única forma que encontramos no projeto para que essa encriptação seja feita é:

- eu relacionando esta DLL em um *webservice* onde eu envio todos os meus parâmetros,
- ela gera meu *hash* criptografado e me retorna os dados,
- eu pego este *hash*, retorno para uma segunda função que envia dados+*hash*
- o servidor entende minha requisição, trata, e me retorna o resultado

no sistema acima, eu tenho 2 requisições que envolvem comunicação e causa um *delay* absurdo e desnecessário nas requisições, e a única solução seria ter essa DLL no meu aplicativo Cordova e ler ela.

Alguém sabe como eu posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Dois pontos: 1) Você está ciente de que precisará de uma versão da "DLL" compilada para cada tipo de dispositivo e arquitetura, correto? No Android seria através de arquivos SO compilados com o NDK, no iOS, não há o equivalente de uma DLL pois isso não é permitido pelas regras da App Store. Já no Windows Phone não estou ciente do processo. 2) Você mencionou WCF. Tem certeza de que sua plataforma alvo suporta WCF? Seria bom deixar esses pontos claros.

Comment: Guilherme, eu entendo isso que você diz, tanto que estou buscando outra solução. Meu problema é que sou apenas o Developer Mobile da solução e a criptografia que foi criada em VB não consigo reproduzir no HTML5 porque a pessoa que criou usou uma biblioteca pra isso. Mesmo eu tentando reproduzir com o CryptoJS, a lib em VB tem um monte de coisa que não consigo entender.

Comment: Você não consegue implementar em Java, criando um plugin para o Cordova só para processar a hash? Ou conversar com o desenvolvedor que fez em VB para liberar o código para tu adaptar. Porque se o tempo das requisições já te preocupa, o tempo para gerar a hash (se for complexa) em JavaScript também não vai ser muito rápido não. Ah, outra alternativa séria reduzir uma requisição, passa os parametros para o servidor gerar a hash e com Curl ou outra biblioteca faz ele solicitar todos dados e retornar tudo para você. Pode ficar mais rápido =)